# No JNDI resources found after automatic publish with Tomcat 7.0.27 and Atomikos 3.7.1

Tags: jndi, tomcat7, atomikos, server.xml, context.xml

I am building a web application using Spring, Tomcat 7.0.27 and Atomikos 3.7.1. 
I followed the integration guidelines from Atomikos: [Tomcat7Integration35](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35). Everything works except two listeners which don't exist anymore in Tomcat 7.0.27. So I did not include these two listeners in my server.xml file.

`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />`

`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>`

Everything works when I start Tomcat for the first time. When I do some code changes and Tomcat try to publish the application automatically, then none of the JNDI resources which were defined in context.xml are found (Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException). I need to stop the server and start it again. By doing this, the application is published successfully.

Has anyone else experienced this? I would appreciate if you could give me any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this problem is solved. I explained the solution in detail here:
[Tomcat 7.0.27 Integration with Atomikos 3.7.1](http://www.atomikos.com/Main/SamanehTorkAbadi)

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others can learn from your success.  Cheers~